# Calling Custom Bapi From Excel Vba Error

Tags: excel, vba

A customized Function Module have been created. I have to access this Function Module from Excel to upload the data and get the return value.

But while accessing the FM, am getting Runtime Error 1001, SAP Remote Function Call.

The code as below :

```
Private Sub btnGroup_Click()  
Dim oRFCCntrl As Object  
Dim oSAPCnct As Object  
Dim oFilTable As Object  

Set oRFCCntrl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")  
Set oSAPCnct = oRFCCntrl.Connection  

If oSAPCnct.Logon(0, False) <> True Then  
        MsgBox "Failed to connect to SAP!", vbCritical  
        Exit Sub  
Else  
        Set oFilTable = oRFCCntrl.Add("/KAR/BAPI_NBR_RANGE_CHECK")  
End If  
End Sub
```

Please help to resolve the issue.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Am able to access the Standard BAPI through the above code, but while accessing the custom module am getting the error.

Comment: do we have to add any reference in VBA ?

Comment: Thank You All. The issue has been resolved. The error occurs due to the FM is not present in that system.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to the FM is not present in that system.